# Azure delete old blobs based on last modified

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to add old blobs to a list and then loop through it and delete them.

So if 7 days have passed since the blob was last modified i want to delete it.
Blobs got a property named last modified, but it seems like its of type bool (?)

Anyone been down this road before?

Something like this:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = CloudStorageServices.GetCloudBlobsContainer();

var blobs = container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Where(b=>b.Properties.LastModified - b.Properties.LastModified.AddDays(7)).TotalHours <= 0);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're more or less on the right path. Try the code below. It will fetch the blobs from a container which have not been modified in last 7 days.

```
    static void GetOldBlobs()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount acc = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("account name", "account key"), false);
        var client = acc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("container name");
        var blobs = container.ListBlobs("", true).OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Where(b => (DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) > b.Properties.LastModified.Value.DateTime)).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no way to get the date when the blob is created right? Or first time uploaded if you're using sas?

Comment: Blobs got a property named last modified. If a user edits that blob, the date is updated. Is it possible to retrieve the date when the blob was uploaded for the first time instead of the last modified date?

Comment: Based on the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx, Blob service returns `Last-Modified` as one of the response headers when a blob is successfully uploaded. May be you can use it. HTH.

Comment: .net core 2.2 ListBlobs() not found